# How to match daily data from monthly using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, time-series, datetime-select

I have montly macroeconomic data series and I am planning to use them for a weekly (every Monday) regression analysis. How can I match a data point which release once a month to my date template( 4 times during that month) since the new point release and so on.

```
for u=2:size(daily,1)
    l=find(dailytemplate(u)==monthly)

    %# when the monthly date is not equal to my daily template
    if isempty(l)
       %# I need a clearver code for this part to find the previous release
       dailyclose(u)=dailyclose(u-1)
    else 
        dailyclose(u)=monthlyclose(l) 
    end
end
```

**UPDATE**  from comment

I have the following monthly macro data. I want to use them to feed the weekly dates. For example, at March 31/03/2012 the `M-input` was `2.7`. So any weekly date after that date should be

```
W_output=2.7
```

until the April 30/04/2012. Then the weekly `W_output` will be `2.3` which is the new monthly point, `M_input`. The following table provides examples for the weekly `W_ouput` and monthly `M_Input`:

```
08/06/2012 1.7
30/06/2012 1.7
01/06/2012 1.7
31/05/2012 1.7
25/05/2012 2.3
30/04/2012 2.3
18/05/2012 2.3
31/03/2012 2.7
11/05/2012 2.3
29/02/2012 2.9
04/05/2012 2.3
31/01/2012 2.9
27/04/2012 2.7
31/12/2011 3
20/04/2012 2.7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
format long g

%Create a vector of dates (what I am assuming your date template looks like, this is march 31 and the next 9 mondays that follow it)
datetemplate = [datenum('2012/03/31')];
for i = 1:10
    datetemplate(i + 1) = datetemplate(i) + 7;
end
datetemplate';

%Your macro ecos input and dates
macrochangedate = [datenum('2012/03/31');datenum('2012/04/30')]
macrochangedate = [macrochangedate [2.7; 2.3]]

for i = 1:size(macrochangedate,1)
    result(datetemplate >= macrochangedate(i,1)) = macrochangedate(i,2);
end
```

Results:

```
result = 
             2.7
             2.7
             2.7
             2.7
             2.7
             2.3
             2.3
             2.3
             2.3
             2.3
             2.3

datestr(datetemplate)

ans =

31-Mar-2012
07-Apr-2012
14-Apr-2012
21-Apr-2012
28-Apr-2012
05-May-2012
12-May-2012
19-May-2012
26-May-2012
02-Jun-2012
09-Jun-2012
```